# How to break GTID Based replication without disabling read only on replicas

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7

How can we break GTID based replication OR cause replication error on MySQL 5.7 without disabling read only on replicas / slaves.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Create table` on **Master**
2. `Drop table` on **Slave**
3. `Drop table` on **Master**

You will get an error on slave, because MySQL could not find the object.

PS: You should consider the **[skip-slave-errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-replica.html#option_mysqld_slave-skip-errors)** config.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But in my case slave is in read_only.